# How to restart CancellationTokenSource after make it cancel in c#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a WPF application in which I am getting signals from a WCF service. So on one side my application is running well and in parallel I need to get a response from a WCF application so if I will get 10 responses from the WCF service then I need to cancel a Task which is waiting for signals.
So this whole process is running well but when I am starting this process again then again I need to start Task Delay for a few seconds and in first time I am cancelling the task using `CancellationTokenSource.Token`.
So again when I try to start `Task.Delay` then I am getting `Token.IsCancellationRequested = true`. So I need to make it false or I need to start `Task.Delay` again.

```cs
public static System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
private void btnSubmit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested == true)
    {
        startAddToPosition(tokenSource.Token);
    }
    else
    {
        startAddToPosition(tokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

I am passing `tokenSource` value to `startAddToPosition` Task. So if `Token` is false then my condition is not working so I need to make `tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested == false`.

```cs
public static async void startAddToPosition(System.Threading.CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        MainWindow.isInLoop = true;
        await Task.Delay(30000, token);
        MainWindow.isInLoop = false;
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        MainWindow.isInLoop = false;
    }
}
```

However when startAddToPosition is start then in parallel I am waiting for signals from WCF service for 30 seconds and if I get signal from WCF service in 5 seconds then I don't want to wait for remaining 25 seconds. So if I get signals from WCF service then I am cancelling task for wait more.

below HandleBroadCast is running in parallel when task waiting for 30 seconds.

```
public static void HandleBroadcast(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     var eventData = (ServiceReference1.EventDataType)sender;
     if (message != "")
          message += "\r\n";
          message += string.Format("{0} (from {1})",
          eventData.EventMessage, eventData.ClientName);

     if (isInLoop == true)
     {
         tokenSource.Cancel();
     }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

So when tokenSource become cancel then I am redirecting to catch section of startAddToPosition method.

So this is whole flow and in that when I click submit button again then it goes to startAddToPosition method but it's getting tokenSource value true. So how can I change value of tokenSource and

if there is any better idea in which I can able to wait for 30 seconds and in parallel get response from WCF service and if I get response from WCF service then I need to cancel that waiting period. Is there any good suggestion which I should replace in implementation ?

Comment: A CTS isn't meant to be reused. It doesn't make sense to reuse or reset it. What would that mean? What would the code that *cancelled* its execution do when that CTS was reset? Start again? Try to execute the same code again? That's not possible, those methods would have exited or thrown cancellation exception, depending on how they were coded

Comment: What are you trying to do and why do you want to reset the CTS? Are you trying to use it as a "Pause" flag?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, when my application become start then I am declaring CTS which is false at first time after then I have write some functions and after finish it I redirecting to `startAddToPosition` method in which I have set delay of 30 seconds because in parallel I need to fetch signals from clients through WCF service and when I am getting those signals then I am cancelling CTS which I have pass to `startAddToPosition` so my task of delay become cancel so I do not need to wait for remaining seconds.

Comment: And again when I redirect to `startAddToPosition` then again I need to make CTS true so my condition can be run without issue but when I am cancelling CTS then it's not becoming true again.

Answer (score 2):

You "restart" a `CancellationTokenSource` by creating a new one:

```
tokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
```

But as Panagiotis mentioned, there could be a better solution, if you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.